# Powershell: How to hide common parameters in powershell help?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing custom cmdlets. While showing help I want to hide the

For ex (help for get-process):

PS C:\source\ESI\EMC.WinApps.Fx.Build\DEBUG\X64\ESIPstoolkit> get-help get-process

NAME
    Get-Process

SYNTAX
    Get-Process [[-Name] ] [-ComputerName ] [-FileVersionInfo] [-Module] []

Whereas help for my cmdlets shows all the common parameters which is kind of clumsy.

Add-MyCmdlet -Path  -Param1  -Param2   [-Index ] -Location  [-Verbose] [-Debug] [-ErrorAction ] [
-WarningAction ] [-ErrorVariable ] [-WarningVariable ] [-OutVariable ] [-
OutBuffer ]

How can I hide these?

Answer:

Looks like I just have to specify the maml xml (help) file for my Commands (module). Then its displaying hte [CommmonParameters].

Thank you,
Dreamer

Comment: You should put your answer as an answer to the question, so you can accept it and the question will show as closed.

Comment: FYI, in v3 CTP, it by default comes as [<CommonParameters>] in the help

Answer (score 0):

Have to set the help maml file for the modules (commands). Then its hiding the common parameters.
Thank you,
Dreamer